# Add simulated left mouse click after page loads swf object

Tags: javascript, flash

I've added a flash game to my site that for some reason requires a left mouse click anywhere on the page after it loads.  The click then enables the arrow keys to work.

I've tried a js based mouse trigger in my html and added an id to my flash object, but it's still not working.  Any advice?

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Donkey Kong</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function swfLoadEvent(fn){
//Ensure fn is a valid function
if(typeof fn !== "function"){ return false; }
//This timeout ensures we don't try to access PercentLoaded too soon
var initialTimeout = setTimeout(function (){
    //Ensure Flash Player's PercentLoaded method is available and returns a value
    if(typeof e.ref.PercentLoaded !== "undefined" && e.ref.PercentLoaded()){
        //Set up a timer to periodically check value of PercentLoaded
        var loadCheckInterval = setInterval(function (){
            //Once value == 100 (fully loaded) we can do whatever we want
            if(e.ref.PercentLoaded() === 100){
                //Execute function
                fn();
                //Clear timer
                clearInterval(loadCheckInterval);
            }
        }, 1500);
    }
}, 200);
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
$("#swf").trigger('click');
},5000);
});
</script>

</head>

<style type="text/css">
body, html{
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
body
{
border: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0px;
}
object {
border: none;
outline: none;
}  
</style>

<body style="background-color: #000000">

<table class="flash-container" style="height: 94%; width:100%">
    <tr style="height: 100%; width:100%">
        <td style="height: 100%; width:100%">

<script type="text/javascript">             
          //This function is invoked by SWFObject once the <object> has been created
var callback = function (e){

//Only execute if SWFObject embed was successful
if(!e.success || !e.ref){ return false; }

swfLoadEvent(function(){
alert("The SWF has finished loading!");

}); 

};

swfobject.embedSWF("donkey_kong.swf", "flashcontent", "550", "400", "9", false, false, false, false, callback);
</script>            

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to poll for 100 percent loaded flash object. Check the solution here:

http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/executing-javascript-when-the-swf-has-finished-loading/

EDIT:
Your current function has HTML in it. Remove the HTML so it looks like this:

```
swfLoadEvent(function(){
    alert("The SWF has finished loading!");

});
```

Comment: I have revised the script, but now I get a blank page!  Please see revised script above.

Comment: You have HTML inside your function.

`swfLoadEvent(function(){

            <object id="swf" width="100%" height="100%">
                <param name="autoPlay" value="true"></param>
                <embed allowfullscreen="true" autoPlay="true" allownetworking="all" allowscriptaccess="always" height="100%" src="images/games/donkey_kong.swf"  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed>
            </object>

    alert("The SWF has finished loading!");

});`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand.  Can you revise script?

Comment: Revised script based on your suggestion...still not working.  See OP above.

Comment: Are you getting a console error? Can you try to console.log the e.ref.PercentLoaded() ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what that means.  Your help was appreciated though.